# Why doesn't re-assigning a pointer to a const int give a compile error?

Tags: c, pointers

This is a question from a test.

```
int main() {
  const int i=1;
  const int *p=&i;
  int j=2;
  const int *q=&j;
  j=3;
  printf("%d", *p+*q);
  int k = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

I understand that both `p` and `q` are pointers to a `const int`.

I thought that it would give a compile error when I declare the pointer to a non-const value, but it works fine; why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between const int\*, const int \* const, and int const \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Comment: Why would you expect a warning? The reassignment is to `j` which is a simple `int`. You can do that all day long.

Comment: @Valentin Bichok The compiler can issue an error if you set  warnings to be  errors. In the program the variable  k is declared but not used. And the compiler can inform you about this issuing an error message.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought that it would give a compile error when I declare the q pointer to a non-const value, but it works fine; why is that??

It would not really make sense to make this non-valid code. If you point with a regular pointer, you can read and write. With a const you can only read, but it's the same underlying type so there's not really anything that can go wrong if you're reading a variable via a regular pointer or a pointer to const. It would be like not being able to read a file from a file system that you have mounted read-only, just because the file itself is not write protected.

Using pointer to const to point at a non-const variable is effectively creating a read-only interface, which makes sense to do. It's commonly used for functions that takes pointers as arguments, but you want to show that the function will not change the content. For instance

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

This library function reads from `src` and writes to `dest`.

However, the opposite will give a warning:

```
const int i=2;
int *p = &i;
```

This yields this:

```
warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
```

which makes perfect sense, since otherwise you could very easily be able to modify a constant.

Answer (score 2):

`const int *q=&j;` is OK because it adds `const`. Your pointer `q` is like a `const` view to the non-const `j`. That pointer can be passed around giving others `const` access to `i` but no write access.

Of course the other way round would not be possible. If you have a `const int k=...;` you cannot take away the `const` by writing `int* pp=&k;`.

Answer (score 1):

First, some standard language:

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 2 Except when it is the operand of the **`sizeof`** operator, the **`_Alignof`** operator, the
> unary **`&`** operator, the **`++`** operator, the **`--`** operator, or the left operand of the **`.`** operator
> or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the
> value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called *lvalue
> conversion*. If the lvalue has qualified type, the value has the unqualified version of the
> type of the lvalue; additionally, if the lvalue has atomic type, the value has the non-atomic
> version of the type of the lvalue; otherwise, the value has the type of the lvalue. If the
> lvalue has an incomplete type and does not have array type, the behavior is undefined. If
> the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been
> declared with the **`register`** storage class (never had its address taken), and that object
> is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been
> performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.
> ...
> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
> ...
> 2    For any qualifier *q*, a pointer to a non-*q*-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to
> the *q*-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers
> shall compare equal.
> ...
> **6.5.16.1 Simple assignment**
> **Constraints**
> 1    One of the following shall hold:<sup>112)</sup>
> ...
>       — the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering
>           the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are
> pointers
>           to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed
> to by the left
>           has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> ...
>
> ---
>
> <sup>112) The asymmetric appearance of these constraints with respect to type qualifiers is due to the conversion
> (specified in 6.3.2.1) that changes lvalues to ‘‘the value of the expression’’ and thus removes any type
> qualifiers that were applied to the type category of the expression (for example, it removes **`const`** but
> not **`volatile`** from the type **`int volatile * const`**).</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

So you can take the address of a non-`const` object and assign it to a `const` pointer.  You can write a new value directly to `j`, but you can't write a new value to `*p`, even though `j` and `*p` designate the same object.

This is a useful and desirable feature.  A common use case is to declare pointer arguments in functions to be `const` as a promise that the function will not attempt to update the pointed-to object, such as in the `strcat` function:

```
char *strcat( char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2 );
```

If I write something like

```
char foo[10] = "foo";
char bar[] = "bar";

strcat( foo, bar );
```

Even though `bar` is not `const`, `strcat` cannot write to it through the `*s2` argument.

But the constraint is asymmetrical - you cannot assign the address of a `const` object to a non-`const` pointer.

In general, you can assign from a less restrictive type to a more restrictive type, but not the other way around.

Comment: I tried checking if what i understood was correct and i'm still not 100% sure.
**But the constraint is asymmetrical - you cannot assign the address of a const object to a non-const pointer.**

I expected this code to fail for two reasons:
1.I assigned the address of a const object (var) to a non const pointer (ip).
2.I managed to change the value of a const object (var).
what am i missing ?

`int main () {
   const int  var = 20; 
   int  *ip = &var;
   *ip = 21;
   printf("Value of *ip variable: %d\n", *ip );
  return 0;
}`